# onActivityResult not fired after waiting room (Google Play Game Services)

Tags: android, google-play-games

I'm testing my multiplayer implementation using Google Play Game Services with 4 distinct devices. Everything is working fine but two things:

1. onInvitationReceived sometimes not firing (only sometimes ¿?)
2. Only in one device (Galaxy Ace), and only when is it who receives the invitation, then both players (inviter and invited) keeps waiting in the waiting room, so onActivity result is never fired. In waiting room I read "Invitation accepted" for both players, but it never closes...

Any advices?

Answer (score 0):

Usually, when listeners are not firing, it's because they are getting garbage-collected. This happens if you use an anonymous listener (`new Listener() { .... }`). To avoid this, make your Activity implement the desired listener interface, and pass in `this` as the listener to `GamesClient` methods.

For more info, take a look at our [troubleshooting guide](https://developers.google.com/games/services/android/troubleshooting#listeners_not_called), in the "Listeners not Called" section.

As for *onActivityResult*, if you are overring BaseGameActivity, make sure you are keeping the `super.onActivityResult(...)` line on your implementation of `onActivityResult`.

Comment: My Activity implement listener interface, so is not garbage collected. And I am already calling super.onActivityResult(...).